# Exception when training data in Predictionio

Tags: python, apache-spark, recommendation-engine, data-science, predictionio

I am trying to Deploy an Recommendation Engine as mentioned in [quick start guide](http://docs.prediction.io/templates/recommendation/quickstart/).
I completed the steps up to build the engine. Now I want to train the Recommendation Engine. I did as mentioned in quick start guide. (execute `pio train`). Then I got the lengthy error log and I couldn't paste all here. So I am putting first few rows of the error.

```
[INFO] [Console$] Using existing engine manifest JSON at /home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/manifest.json
[INFO] [Runner$] Submission command: /home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/vendors/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --class io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow --jar/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-recommendation_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,file:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bndation/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-recommendation-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar --files file:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/conf/log4j.properties --driver/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/conf:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/lib/postgresql-9.4-1204.jdbc41.jar:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/lib/mysql-connector-jav file:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/lib/pio-assembly-0.9.6.jar --engine-id qokYFr4rwibijNjabXeVSQKKFrACyrYZ --engine-version ed29b3e2074149d483aa85b6b1ea35a52dbbdb9a --et file:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/engine.json --verbosity 0 --json-extractor Both --env PIO_ENV_LOADED=1,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pFS_BASEDIR=/root/.pio_store,PIO_HOME=/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6,PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=/root/.pio_store/engines,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=PGSQL,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=PGSQL,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_PASSWORD=pio,PIURCES_PGSQL_TYPE=jdbc,PIO_FS_TMPDIR=/root/.pio_store/tmp,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_USERNAME=pio,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDGSQL,PIO_CONF_DIR=/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/conf
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting datasource params...
[INFO] [WorkflowUtils$] No 'name' is found. Default empty String will be used.
[INFO] [Engine] Datasource params: (,DataSourceParams(MyApp3,None))
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting preparator params...
[INFO] [Engine] Preparator params: (,Empty)
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting serving params...
[INFO] [Engine] Serving params: (,Empty)
[WARN] [Utils] Your hostname, test-digin resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.2.191 instead (on interface p5p1)
[WARN] [Utils] Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[INFO] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.2.191:56574]
[WARN] [MetricsSystem] Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
[INFO] [Engine$] EngineWorkflow.train
[INFO] [Engine$] DataSource: duo.DataSource@6088451e
[INFO] [Engine$] Preparator: duo.Preparator@1642eeae
[INFO] [Engine$] AlgorithmList: List(duo.ALSAlgorithm@a09303)
[INFO] [Engine$] Data sanity check is on.
[INFO] [Engine$] duo.TrainingData does not support data sanity check. Skipping check.
[INFO] [Engine$] duo.PreparedData does not support data sanity check. Skipping check.
[WARN] [BLAS] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
[WARN] [BLAS] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
[WARN] [LAPACK] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
[WARN] [LAPACK] Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.writeObject(List.scala:379)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
```

what can I do to overcome this isssue?

Comment: It seems like memory issue. Have you tried increasing the driver-memory limit?

Comment: I am using 4 cores, 6GB RAM and Ubuntu 14.04 server. I monitor the performance of the server while I am training the model but it didn't use the swap memory or even didn't take all 6GB. So I think the exception is something else.

Comment: But judging from the exception you posted above is indeed memory related. Try running with flag `--driver-memory` and `--executor-memory` with like `4G` or above and see if it helps

Comment: I tried `pio train -- --master spark://127.0.1.1:7077 --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 5G`
Then I got following error.

`[Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.2.191:59748]
[WARN] [MetricsSystem] Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
[ERROR] [SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler] Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]`

Comment: How large is your dataset to train? Are you just using the default train data? Try without --executor-memory flag

Comment: yes. using the sample data set for recommender as mentioned in quick start guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error says `java.lang.StackOverflowError` for that you can reduce the `numIterations parameter` in `engine.json` file. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133172/predictionio-engine).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on an 8GB MacOS machine . Changing the numIterations parameter in /MyRecommendation/engine.json to 10 (used to be 20 by default) solved the issue for me. Using --driver-memory and --executor-memory with pio train did not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.